# How can I set the same type as class in method's parameter following PEP484?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, types, pycharm

My question is related with the new Python's type hints. I'm trying to add a type hint in an object's method who has a parameter of the same type of the object, but PyCharm are marking me as error (`unresolved reference 'Foo'`). The problem is as follows:

```
class Foo:

    def foo_method(self, other_foo: Foo):
        return "Hello World!"
```

So the question is how to define the type of `other_foo` parameter properly. Maybe `__class__` is correct?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Inside of the class, the class is not defined yet, causing a `NameError` (and PyCharm to complain).

To get around this, use a [forwarding reference](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references):

```
class Foo:
    def foo_method(self, other_foo: "Foo"):
        return "Hello World!"
```

Basically, if a type annotations is a string, it is `eval`ed [when the type is requested](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_type_hints) (in the global scope rather than the scope of the class `Foo`), so it can evaluate to the `Foo` class.

---

You can also use the [`annotations`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0563/) feature, which will turn all annotations into strings:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

class Foo:
    def foo_method(self, other_foo: Foo):
        return "Hello World!"

# Foo.foo_method.__annotations__ == {'other_foo': 'Foo'}
# typing.get_type_hints(Foo.foo_method) == {'other_foo': Foo}
```

This is available since 3.7, and was slated to become the default behaviour in 3.10 but was postponed.